# Getting wrong result while removing all NA value columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am getting wrong result while removing all NA value column in R

data file : https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv

```
trainingData <- read.csv("D:\\pml-training.csv",na.strings = c("NA","", "#DIV/0!"))
```

Now I want to remove all the column which only has NA's

Approach 1: here I mean read all the column which has more than 0 sum and not NA

```
aa <- trainingData[colSums(!is.na(trainingData)) > 0]
length(colnames(aa))
```

154 columns

Approach 2: As per this query, it will give all the columns which is NA and sum = 0, but it is giving the result of column which does not have NA and gives expected result

```
bb <- trainingData[,colSums(is.na(trainingData)) == 0]
length(colnames(bb))
```

60 columns (expected)

Can someone please help me to understand what is wrong in first statement and what is right in second one

Comment: Are you forgetting a comma in the first one?

Comment: With the first method you are selecting all the columns that have *at least* one non-`NA` element. With the second you are selecting columns that don't have *any* `NA` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aa <- trainingData[,colSums(!is.na(trainingData)) > 0]
length(colnames(aa))
```

You convert the dataframe to a boolean dataframe with `!is.na(trainingData)`, and find all columns where there is more than one TRUE (so non-NA) in the column.  So this returns all columns that have at least one non-NA value, which seem to be all but 6 columns.

---

```
bb <- trainingData[colSums(is.na(trainingData)) == 0]
length(colnames(bb))
```

You convert the dataframe to boolean with `is.na(trainingData)` and return all values where there is no TRUE (no NA) in the column. This returns all columns where there are no missing values (i.e. no NA's).

Example as requested in comment:

```
df  = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(NA,1,1),c=c(NA,NA,NA))
bb <- df[colSums(is.na(df)) == 0]

> df
  a  b  c
1 1 NA NA
2 2  1 NA
3 3  1 NA
> bb
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

---

So the statements are in fact different. If you want to remove all columns that are only NA's, you should use the first statement. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see a - sign? I added a simple example to illustrate in the answer, hope that helps. As you see, the a column is the only one where the column sum==0, because it has no NA values.

Comment: Thanks, Now I got the answer in very good way, really nice explanation

Comment: I am a new user and not getting such option, if you guide me how can I accept  it as answer, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: There should be a checkmark just below the votes of my answer. If you can't find it, no problem ;)